# Removing from, to cc from email thread

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I am trying to filter/remove the "from:","to:","cc:" from a email using nltk library in python.
Is there any way of doing this.
PS: I am new to python

Here is the thread of the mail

Hello ,

Some Text

Thanks,

Name and details

Name and details

From: xxx  // Here I don't want to read this field

Sent: Thursday, March 24, 2016 11:20 AM   // Here I don't want to read this field

To: yyy.com // Here I don't want to read this field

Subject: some text

Hello ,

Some text

Thanks!

Name and details

From: some name // Here I don't want to read this field

Sent: Friday, March 4, 2016 2:40 PM // Here I don't want to read this field

To: yyy.com // Here I don't want to read this field

Subject: some text

Hey ,

some text

---

Comment: I find it hard to imagine how "[an] email dump which is in [an] excel file" could be constructed.  Removing email headers from individual messages is easy, but without seeing your data representation, this is way too vague.  Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: No I am trying to read the email  which is in a column in a excel file and have to filter out certain things like "from:" ,"to:" etc.

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's not really okay for an email to not have a `From:` header.  Should the email be turned into an invalid message or should the `From:` header value be replaced with something like `Undisclosed:;`?

Comment: @tripleee no you are not getting  the whole mail is in a thread which is in text format which contains description of mail, subject, To:, From: ,Cc:

Comment: @tripleee I think those fields are in text format so it can be filtered out using regex. Need a suggestion.

Comment: I don't think you need or want to use a regex here.  You need to cope with wrapped header lines, too. Anyway, what did you try, and how did it fail?  Please [edit] your question to show us your current code

Comment: @ i don't know where to start actually. I am new to this

Comment: `line.startswith('From:')` would tell you whether a line starts with that token.  If what you have is just a sequence of lines, not proper email messages, maybe reshape the question into "how do I `if any([line.startswith(x) for x in ['From:', 'Sent:', 'To:', 'Cc:']]): continue`"

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.5+ this is fairly simple.

```
from email import message_from_file  # or message_from_bytes if you want that

with open(filename) as fh:
    msg = message_from_file(fh)
del msg['from'], msg['to'], msg['cc']
back_to_bytes = msg.as_bytes()
```

This will simply zap the header lines as if they never existed.  Removing the `From:` header in particular is problematic, but if you don't feed the resulting message back to anything which actually handles email messages, that should not be a problem.

There is nothing specific to NLTK about email messages, and indeed, you will probably need to understand more about email before you even try to process a body part with NLTK.  In particular, you should understand how `multipart/alternative` message parts work -- you should choose one or the other, and probably run it through some kind of formatting filter (HTML to text if you pick the HTML part if one is available, for example -- many mailers these days offer a `text/plain` part which just clicks through to a web URL where the actual content is in HTML at the end of the link).

Comment: Prior to 3.4 there was a somewhat more edgy `email` library which is still available, but somewhat more thorny to use.  This is documented as "legacy API" in the 3.6+ documentation.  The documentation was only updated in 3.6, but the modern API was already available in the previous release.